# Do browsers create new TCP connections for each HTTP requests?

Tags: networking, browser, http, tcp

So I know that HTTP is basically just a text protocol over TCP, and that TCP is state / connection based. That means that the browser has to connect over TCP to a server before doing an HTTP request. Question then: do browsers typically create a new TCP connection for each HTTP request?

Browsers could just open a TCP request and keep it alive as long as the user is still browsing on that server, but then servers would have to use a big amount of maximum connections to handle that. But then again, if the browsers create a connection for each request, and the user browses a lot on the same server, that would seem like a waste. How does it usually work? Maybe through use of a timer?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In HTTP/0.9 (not used anymore), each request used a separate TCP connection, and the end of a response was signalled by closing the connection.

In HTTP/1.0, separate connections are still the official default. However,  an unofficial but very widely supported "`Connection: Keep-Alive`" request header can be used to request a persistent connection if the server supports it.

In HTTP/1.1, persistent connections [became the default](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-8.1), and the old single-request behavior has to be requested explicitly. Usually multiple (2–5) persistent connections are used.

(Optionally requests may be [pipelined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining), though this turned out to be difficult to implement and creates more issues than it solves (head-of-line blocking, etc.), so nobody uses HTTP/1.x pipelining.)

HTTP/2 (aka [SPDY](http://www.chromium.org/spdy)) was specifically designed to multiplex many requests at the same time. It has a framing/packetization layer which allows responses to arrive in any order and even simultaneously.

Resources: [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) and [RFC 2616 section 8.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-8.1).

Comment: Another interesting article mentioning the same https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Connection_management_in_HTTP_1.x

Answer (score 7):

There is "Connection: Keep-Alive" header. See [enwiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) for details.

You can use Wireshark to capture and analyse connections and see all headers.

Comment: Fiddler is 1. Not an Open Source software; 2. Windows-only.